# Filtering list violates open–closed principle

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, design-patterns

I wrote a method that filters list by parameters, it works pretty good. But I'm worried about **violation of "*open–closed principle*"**.

> **Open–closed principle** states that "software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for
> modification"

Currently if I want to add one more filter I need to **modificate** *Params* class and *Filter* method.

I want to ask **how to refactor these entities to be extendible?** or maybe it's dumb question and I don't need to refactor here anything? I'll appreciate any thoughts of this.

Filtering method:

```
public IEnumerable<Meeting> Filter(Params params)
{
    IEnumerable<Meeting> selectedMeetings =  new List<Meeting>(_dataContext.Meetings);

    if (request.Description is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByDescription(request.Description);

    if (request.Name is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByResponsiblePerson(request.Name);

    if (request.Category is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByCategory(request.Category);

    if (request.Type is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByType(request.Type);

    if (request.StartDate is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByStartDate(request.StartDate);

    if (request.EndDate is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByEndDate(request.EndDate);
           
    if (request.AttendeeCount is not null)
        selectedMeetings = selectedMeetings.GetByAttendeesCount(request.AttendeeCount);

    return selectedMeetings;
}
```

Params class:

```
 public class Params
    {
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Category { get; set; }
        public string? Type { get; set; }
        public string? StartDate { get; set; }
        public string? EndDate { get; set; }
        public string? AttendeeCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding of that principle. Open-Close, for example with a List, means "you allow other code to modify the data in a list (add, remove, reorder, edit element), but not modify the inner working of the List (how its saved to memory, etc).

Comment: I'd worry about the repeated assignment to `input`, or using IEnumerables rather than recomputing Lists with each method call, way before checking if some buzzword principle is being followed.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks! removed `input` assigments and chaged from `List` to `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the filtering logic to be extensible, you could create a base class for filter criteria:

```
public abstract class FilterCriteria 
{
  IEnumerable<Meetings> Filter(IEnumerable<Meetings> meetings, string input);
}
```

For each criteria, you'd create a class that derives from `FilterCriteria`, e.g.:

```
public class DescriptionFilterCriteria : FilterCriteria
{
  public override IEnumerable<Meetings> Filter(IEnumerable<Meetings> meetings, string input)
  {
    return meetings.GetByDescription(input);
  }
}
```

Your `Filter` method would receive a list of filters instead of a `Params` instance and loop over it:

```
public List<Meetings> Filter(IEnumerable<FilterCriteria> criteria)
{
    IEnumerable<Meetings> selectedMeetings = new List<Meetings>(_dataContext.Meetings);

    foreach (var crit in criteria)
      selectedMeetings = crit.Filter(selectedMeetings, input);

    return selectedMeetings;
}
```

If you need to create another filter criteria, you derive a new class from `FilterCriteria`; you do not have to change `Params` and the global `Filter` method anymore.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! This is what I wanted. The only thing I would like to change here is in `FilterCriteria` abstract class instead of `Filter` method parameter `string input` add to class property `public string Input { get; set; }`.